# RSS reader that can sync across computers?

Tags: software-recommendation, sync, rss

I am using ubuntu 10.10 64bit. I am in need of a service or a reader that can synchronise my feeds across computers and platforms, something like feeddemon has for windows. RSSOwl is by far the best reader i have come across, but it lacks this feature. I dont want to use online readers like google reader. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: When you say "cross-platform" does that mean you need something that works on Windows and Mac as well?

Comment: I'm looking for a desktop and a mobile client that keep in sync, perhaps using guid's?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a portable version of RSSOwl, I use it on my pendrive when I'm on a different computer and just sync (automatically) my "rssowl portable/data" folder to the one on my Ubuntu desktop... search on portableapps.com for portable rssowl.

Answer (score 3):

If by synchronisation, you mean that you want items to be mark as 'read' on each computer and platform you should definitevely use Google Reader as your web rss reader.

Then, you can use Liferea on your Ubuntu desktop, it synchronises with Google Reader from 1.6 version.

Just use Software center to install it.

Comment: Yes thats exactly what i mean with synchronisation and cross platform. I would have loved liferea, but it seems very sluggish. Anyways thank you very much for the answer.

Answer (score 2):

I use "liferea" which I think is really good.

[image: Install via the software center]
Or you can install it by using the command 'sudo apt-get install liferea"

`nrss` is another option.

Comment: is there any option to sync liferea feeds across computers?